# Can I use two related objects as composite key in Doctrine bundled with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Object is ArticleVote and it has two related objects: User and Article. This creates user_id and article_id columns in ArticleVote table. Can I go without using "id" as an id of the table and use a composite key that consists of unique combinaiton of user_id and article_id in ArticleVote talble?

Also, is this supported in Doctrine bundled with Symfony2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's support, read: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html